# nginx serves content/ssl from a different host via HTTPS

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have the latest nginx version on a Ubuntu Server 14.04. I host a few domains and I am now trying to implement letsencrypt on all of them. I already have one domain with a comodo certificate, let's call it `domainone.com`, working just fine. I've set up a second domain, say ```` domaintwo.com``` with letsencrypt, but when I try to access the ````domaintwo.com`via HTTPS I get the content from`domainone.com` and an invalid certificate warning.

Here are the nginx config for the two domains:

domainone.com:

```
server {
   listen         80;
   server_name    domainone.com www.domainone.com;
   rewrite     ^   https://www.domainone.com$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name domainone.com www.domainone.com; 
    root /usr/share/nginx/domainone.com/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-domainone.com.conf;

    if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }
    ...
}
```

domaintwo.com:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name domaintwo.com www.domaintwo.com;
    return 301 https://www.domaintwo.com$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-domaintwo.com.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    root /usr/share/nginx/domaintwo.com/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }
    ...
}
```

Nginx Version:

```
$ nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.10.1
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
TLS SNI support enabled 
...
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your domaintwo.com server doesn't have the server_name declaration:

```
  server_name domaintwo.com www.domaintwo.com;
```

Because of this Nginx chooses the first domain that supports HTTPS when an HTTPS request comes in.

I have a [tutorial on Nginx/Let's Encrypt](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-5-free-https-https2-for-wordpress-using-lets-encrypt-aws/) that might be useful.

Comment: It's one of those super simple things you sometimes completely miss because it's so obvious.

Comment: indeed it is :))